# How can I find functions whose names have been changed by macros in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, macros, visual-studio-2015

I'm porting a large (100-150k lines) C++ codebase to support Windows, and have run across a few places where functions' names were being changed due to macros in the Windows headers, `GetClassName` being one of them. Now, I've already handled the places that I noticed by undefining them after the Windows header is included, however, I want to be sure that I have dealt with all the names in the project that may have been modified by the headers. What is the best way to go about this? I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: May be some VS external text replacement tool would work efficiently?

Comment: maybe you can diff the source code after its been through the preprocessor stage. I do not know what the directive is for VS though.

Comment: Wrapping function names in parentheses in all cases should work for you. Processing the output of some `ctags` utility that reasonably understands C++ should work for getting all function names. Were this C, you could just use `sed` to replace all instances of each function with parentheses-wrapped names to aid conversion automation, but things like `MyObject::GetClassName` add a new depth to the complexity. Requiring such a convention would avoid the issue entirely. This solution won't work for your own function-like macros, but that's why I prefer inline functions within a namespace...